# Order and degree of Ordinary differential equations.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Question is can we always define order and degree of ordinary differential equation?

According to me if we take differential equation as $$e^{y’}+y+1=0$$ then it’s first order differential equation but it’s degree is not define.

Again if I consider differential equations as $$y’+y’’+y’’’+\cdots=0$$

then order is also not defines . Am I right ? Please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: I found a paper which you may find relevant: https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82381463.pdf

Comment: The second differential equation is of infinite order, but may only be defined in terms of limits...

Comment: @Trebor So can i say that order may not defined always?

Comment: Actually the definition of ODE's usually excludes the second equation. So the order is always finite and defined.

Comment: @Trebor can you give me some reference regarding this ....thanks...

Answer (score 1):

**Question:** *Can we always define order and degree of ordinary differential equation* ?

**Answer:** No, we can't always define degree of ordinary differential equation. The conditions to find the degree of differential equation is that the function should only be polynomial function. If the differential equation contains logarithm, exponential and trigonometric function of the derivative then degree is not defined i.e. the equation has to be polynomial function to define degree of a differential equation.

But order of a differential equation is always defined.

---

Since your first equation $~e^{y'}+y+1=0~$, contains exponential function of the derivative, so for this case degree is not defined but it is of first order.

Now for the second equation $~y'+y''+y'''+\cdots=0~$ is an infinite polynomial. So it has degree $~=1~$ and order is infinite.

Comment: his degree is 1 in this equation?? It is infinite polynomial.

Comment: @nmaanta again infinite is not a real number how can we say that order is infinite ?

Comment: @neelkanth, order of a differential equation may be infinite. You can Google for it.  There are so many paper available for Differential equations of infinite order.

Comment: Degree of a differential equation is the power of its highest derivative, after the equation has been made rational and integral in all of its derivatives. Now since all the terms that are visible here are of degree $~1~$, so we can assume that the highest derivative term is also of degree $~1~$.

Answer (score 0):

$e^{y'}+1+y=0$ is first order ODE without a degree. For having degree the ODE needs to be an algebraic relation of $y,y',y'',...$ but here $e^{y'}$ is transcendental. Also it is a nonlinear ODE as $y,y',,y''$ do not occur linearly: $e^{y'}$ is non-linear. Order is the highest order-derivative used.
So in your question the degree is not defined and order is 1. So in an ODE
degree may or may not be defined but order is always defined.

For example $y=y'+y'^3$ is a first order, 3-rd degree non-linear ODE. But
$y=y''+\sin(y'^3)$ is second order nonlinear ODE without a degree.

Comment: Zafar DSc sir what about second question of order......

Comment: @neelkanth the order of ODE is the  highesyt order derivative used.

Comment: so can i say that order may not always defined?

Comment: @neelkanth  No. Iin an ODE order is alwyas defined as order is the highest order derivative used but degree may or may not be defined. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the first equation has both order and degree defined.

Here's how

$e^y′+y+1=0$ can be rewritten as

$\Rightarrow e^y′ = -y -1$  Now take log on both sides.

$\Rightarrow y′ = log|-y -1|$

$\Rightarrow y′ = log|y + 1|$

Now in this equation both degree and order are defined which is 1.

When we talk about the second equation

$y′+y′′+y′′′+⋯=0$

See differential equations are analogous to polynomials, basically they are polynomials with $y, y',y''$ etc.. Since we can have polynomials with infinite degree we can also have differential equations with infinite order.

So for the second differential equation, one might consider that the order is infinite and degree is 1 as we see in the given series all the terms are linear,i.e, they are raised to the power 1, thus definitely, the last time, which is the nth derivative of $y$, will also be raised to the power 1 and hence both order and degree can be defined in this case. Order = Infinite and Degree = 1.